# Is it possible to fetch GPS location ios8 directly from appDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, gps, core-location

I am working on an app in ios8+ in which I have to fetch the location of the user. I am able to fetch the location when I use a CLLocationManager in a screen (viewcontroller). But when I try to fetch the location from the AppDelegate directly, there seems to be some problem and I am not getting any location (the flow is not entering the delegate methods).
Can someone help me with this.

This is the code I used :

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Can you help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `CLLocationManagerDelegate` to AppDelegate.h

`@interface AppDelegate : NSObject < UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate> {`

2. Add `CLLocationManager` object as property to AppDelegate.m

You have to implement `CLLocationManager` object as property.

`@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@end`

3. Replace `locationManager` to `self.locationManager` in AppDelegate.m

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];`

ref. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/

> Keeping a strong reference to the location manager object is required until all tasks involving that object are complete. Because most location manager tasks run asynchronously, storing your location manager in a local variable is insufficient.

Comment: Cool! It worked!
I am confused though.. why didnt it work earlier? What difference did adding a property do?

Comment: @auditya You have to keep CLLocationManager instance. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Also know that CoreLocation permissions have changed with iOS 8. If you don't request the new permissions authorizations, CoreLocation doesn't do anything. It fails quietly because the delegate methods are never called.

[Try this link](http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/)

While the article is very detailed and long, the actual code fix can be as minor as this:

```
if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
```

And you have to add a value to info.plist, which is the message to display in the permissions alert. See screen grab.

[image]

Key: NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

Value: Location is required to find out where you are (You can change that to whatever you want)

Comment: I have already added the keys to the plist and I am able to fetch the location when I access it through a view controller. But I am not able to fetch it when I am trying to get the location from appdelegate directly (so that I can get the location directly on opening the app instead of when opening the viewcontroller)
Can you help me with how to get the location directly from the appdelegate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913239/singleton-for-location-updating-multiple-views